# Installing Chromium on Alpine Linux, strange error

Tags: docker, alpine

I have a Dockerfile setup to install Alpine and Chromium. A few weeks ago the package was working properly and I was able to build with it properly however recently I'm having trouble with the build failing on a Chromium dependency. Here's the Docker:

```
FROM balenalib/odroid-xu4-alpine-node
WORKDIR /var/arbiter

RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies make gcc g++ python && \
  apk add --no-cache krb5-dev zeromq-dev && npm install -g node-gyp

# Install necessaries for sharp and other dependencies
RUN apk add --update \
  --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
  fftw-dev

RUN apk add --update \
  --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
  vips-tools

RUN apk add --update \
  --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
  vips-dev

# Lets try this again
RUN \
  echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
  && apk --no-cache update \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gifsicle pngquant optipng libjpeg-turbo-utils \
    udev ttf-opensans chromium \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

The errors being returned are:

```
[main]     OK: 13195 distinct packages available
[main]     fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/armhf/APKINDEX.tar.gz
[main]     fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/armhf/APKINDEX.tar.gz
[main]     fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/armhf/APKINDEX.tar.gz
[main]     ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
[main]     
[main]       .build-deps-0:
[main]         masked in: cache
[main]         satisfies: world[.build-deps]
[main]       chromium (missing):
[main]         required by:
[main]     Removing intermediate container 6b67e7b77e1f
[main]     The command '/bin/sh -c echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories   && apk --no-cache update   && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps     gifsicle pngquant optipng libjpeg-turbo-utils     udev ttf-opensans chromium   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I can see that the package was recently rebuilt as of Jan 2: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/chromium but I'm not sure why/how it effects this.

How can I ensure a successful build and avoid this error (which I don't even totally understand).

Comment: That is not your package. [This](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/armhf/chromium) is your package. See [#5701](https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/5701). It's supposedly built but completely absent. Better contact the maintainers.

Comment: But it's very strange that it was available and working a few weeks ago. The same commands were operating nicely.

Comment: Yep, now it's a 404. Again, you should contact the distro maintainers for that package. It's either their fault, or something they have to fix anyway.

Comment: I just submitted an issue with the Alpina managers, but I doubt they'll get back in a reasonable amount of time. I'm wondering if it makes sense to attempt compiling Chromium directly. I don't think that'll be an easy/simple thing but not really sure what my other options are.

Comment: Build on a different container/distro? And consider using a 64-bit Linux; it has much better performance than 32-bit ARM.

Comment: We're building for Odroid devices. Our platform gets deployed via the Balena Cloud for microdevice management. So switching to a 64-bit Linux isn't going to totally work. THanks for your help!

Comment: Update: the Alpine guys know this is an issue as there were build errors. They're asking for patches...and I would if I knew how to support them. :-/

Comment: @ddibiase could you please link to the relevant Alpine thread, if any (forum, mailing list)?